# Gated check-in in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm working on a team of 40+ developers and I want to trigger my build in Visual Studio Team Service in such a manner that the build triggers after fixed number of check-ins, neither a continuous build, nor a scheduled build.

How to schedule the build in such manner?

Comment: What's the problem you are trying to solve? Too many builds? On the triggers page, when you enable Continuous Integration,  there's this checkbox: 'Batch changes while a build is in progress'. Maybe this could help you out.

Comment: Yes. Actually, too many builds is a sub-problem. My main problem is to run a build after accumulating a set of check-ins from the developers, or wait for a specific time after which the build triggers automatically(not a daily scheduled build.)
So, how to achieve that?

Comment: But why wouldn't you just run a build after every check-in? Having feedback after every check-in is very valuable. Accumulating them makes it harder to find errors when the build fails. So, if slow builds is your problem shouldn't you be fixing that?

Comment: To answer your question: this cannot be done out-of-the-box. You could write a script that uses the api to query the number of commits since the last build. Then run this script every x minutes. Here's a ref to the api commit documentation: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/commits and here you can find the documentation for builds: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds

Comment: Gated check-in is queue the build before the code really checkin the TFVC repo. But your requirement is after a set of check-ins, then queue the build. If CI build and scheduled build is not meet your situation, you should develop the way to trigger build by yourself with rest api https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfvc/changesets.